# TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined

Tags: json, node.js, express, mocha.js, body-parser

I've created a fixture file to handle my JSON datas used to write tests.

Before each test, I want my data to be filled with seed data.
After each test, I want my data to be empty

Courses.json :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Ma course"
  }
]
```

CoursesFixture.js :

```
const { courseList } = require('./courses')

mockData = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Ma course"
  }
]

module.exports = {
  up: () => {
    courseList.splice(0)
    courseList.push.apply(courseList, mockData)
  },

  down: () => {
    courseList.splice(0)
  }
}
```

CoursesTest.js :

```
const request = require("supertest")
require('chai').should()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const app = require('./../../app')
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const listeDeCourses = require("../fixtures/courses")
const listeDeCoursesFixture = require("../fixtures/coursesFixture")

describe('Courses', () =>{

    beforeEach(() => { listeDeCoursesFixture.up() })
    afterEach(() => { listeDeCoursesFixture.down() })

    describe('Delete course list', ()=>{
        it("Should delete a list of course", ()=>{
           return  request(app).get('/course')
                        .then((res) => {
                           res.body.should.have.lengthOf(1)
                           request(app).delete('/course').send({"id":"1"})
                           .then((res) => {
                                res.body.should.have.lengthOf(0)
                           })

                        }).catch((err)  =>{
                            throw new Error(err);
                         })
                    })
                })
    describe('Create course list', () =>{
        it("Should create a list of courses", () =>{
            return request(app).post('/course').send({"id":3,"title":"Première course"}).then((res) => {
                res.status.should.be.eq(200)
                const listCourses = res.body 
                const lastCourse = res.body[1]
                listCourses.should.be.a('array')
                lastCourse.id.should.be.eq(3)
                lastCourse.title.should.be.eq("Première course")
                listCourses[listCourses.length - 1].should.be.eq(lastCourse)
            }).catch((err) => {
                throw new Error(err)
            })
        })
    })

    describe('Get course list', ()=>{
        it("Should get a list of all courses", ()=>{
           return  request(app).get('/course')
                        .then((res) => {
                           res.body.should.have.lengthOf(1)
                        }).catch((err)  =>{
                           console.log(err)
                            throw new Error(err);
                         })
        })
    })
})
```

My problem is that when I launch my test I have an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined
```

I think the problem is in CoursesFixture.js and surely a syntax error somewhere but I can't find where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const { courseList } = require('./courses')` should be `const courseList = require('./courses')`?